# Concatenate two cell arrays of strings with a space in between?

Tags: matlab, string-concatenation, cell-array

How can I concatenate:

```
A = {'hello'; 'hi'; 'hey'}
```

with

```
B = {'Ben'; 'Karen'; 'Lisa'}
```

with a space in between to get:

```
C = {'hello Ben'; 'hi Karen'; 'hey Lisa'}
```

Is there a fast non-looping way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strcat()`, although it performs a loop:

```
strcat(A,{' '}, B)
```

where the blank is preserved by enclosing it within a cell.

Alternatively, [FEX:CStrCatStr](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24341-cstrcatstr) is a mex routine which achieves a 10x speedup (depending on testing environment):

```
CStrCatStr(A,' ', B)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on CStrCatStr!

Answer (score 2):

A faster (albeit less elegant) alternative to `strcat` that concatenates strings is a combination of the `sprintf` and `textscan` commands:

```
C = [A; B];
C = textscan(sprintf('%s %s\n', C{:}), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
```

#### Benchmark

Here's the benchmark code:

```
A = {'hello' ; 'hi' ; 'hey'};
B = {'Ben' ; 'Karen' ; 'Lisa'};

%// Solution with strcat
tic
for k = 1:1000
    C1 = strcat(A, ' ', B);
end
toc

%// Solution with sprintf and textscan
tic
for k = 1:1000
    C2 = [A; B];
    C2 = textscan(sprintf('%s %s\n', C2{:}), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
end
toc
```

The results are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.022659 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.006011 seconds.
```

Comment: I was looking only for a simpler answer concerning the language... tic strcat(A,{' '}, B) toc runs faster than both loops above. Anyway +1 deserved thanks

Comment: @DBS One of the loops above _IS_ the `strcat` solution, and the benchmark clearly shows it's slower (the loops are there for more accurate time measurements). But if you're looking for simplicity, it's indeed the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using cellfun:

```
cellfun(@(x,y) [x, ' ', y], A, B, 'UniformOutput', false)

ans = 
{
  [1,1] = hello Ben
  [2,1] = hi Karen
  [3,1] = hey Lisa
}
```